# Assistance with complicated SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table on which I need to run an UPDATE statement. This table has about 250,000 records, so optimized performance is important.

Here is the relevant database schema and some sample data.

```
audit_logs
-- id -- ticket_id -- ip_address      -- created_at                 --
-- 10 -- 100       -- 100.101.102.103 -- 2014-08-22 11:17:28.325844 --
-- 11 -- 100       -- 100.101.102.103 -- 2014-08-23 12:18:28.325844 --
-- 12 -- 101       -- 200.1.2.3       -- 2014-08-24 13:19:28.325844 --
-- 13 -- 101       -- 201.2.3.4       -- 2014-08-25 14:20:28.325844 --
-- 14  - 101       -- 202.3.4.5       -- 2014-08-26 15:21:28.325844 --
-- 15  - 102       -- 102.12.34.56    -- 2014-08-27 16:22:28.325844 --
```

Here is what I need to do. For any ticket_id that has records with more than 1 IP address, I need to set the ticket_id to NULL for every IP address except the first. Here is an example result for the data above.

```
audit_logs
-- id -- ticket_id -- ip_address      -- created_at                 --
-- 10 -- 100       -- 100.101.102.103 -- 2014-08-22 11:17:28.325844 --
-- 11 -- 100       -- 100.101.102.103 -- 2014-08-23 12:18:28.325844 --
-- 12 -- 101       -- 200.1.2.3       -- 2014-08-24 13:19:28.325844 --
-- 13 -- NULL      -- 201.2.3.4       -- 2014-08-25 14:20:28.325844 --
-- 14  - NULL      -- 202.3.4.5       -- 2014-08-26 15:21:28.325844 --
-- 15  - 102       -- 102.12.34.56    -- 2014-08-27 16:22:28.325844 --
```

So, there can be multiple records with the same ticket. But, if there is more than 1 IP address associated with a ticket, then every record with an IP address other than the 1st one that was seen needs to be nulled out.

The actual RDBMS that I am using is Postgres. What's the easiest way do this? Thanks all.

Comment: How do want to determine which row is 'first' ; creation date?

Comment: It could be one of two things. Either the smallest 'created_at' time for a given ticket_id or the smallest 'id' value. Ordering on both should produce the same results.

Comment: No, the ticket_id for record 11 should NOT be null, because the IP address values for records 10 and 11 are the same. I only want to null out the ticket when the IP address is different.

Comment: Is it possible to have a ticket_id with multiple duplicated ip_address'es? e.g. ticket_id 101 might have an extra row with ip_address 200.1.2.3; if so, do you want only the first row preserved (not NULLed) or the first ip_address?

Comment: The first ip_address/ticket_id pairing should be preserved, even across multiple records. But if another IP address ever appears in a later record with that same ticket_id, the ticket_id should be set to NULL. There is actually an answer below which worked as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Postgres does not yet support a `count(distinct ..)` as a window function so it's a bit more complicated than necessary:

```
update audit_logs
  set ticket_id = null
from (
  select a.id, 
         a.ticket_id,
         row_number() over (partition by a.ticket_id order by a.created_at) as rn
  from audit_logs a
  join  (
    select ticket_id
    from audit_logs
    group by ticket_id
    having count(distinct ip_address) > 1
  ) t on t.ticket_id = a.ticket_id
) x
where x.id = audit_logs.id
and x.rn > 1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a632c/1

The innermost select (alias `t`) get's all `ticket_id` that have more than one IP address. This is then joined with the base table to count the rows. The result of that is then used in the `update` to find the rows that should be updated.

Not sure about the performance, it largely depends on how many rows the inner most select will return.

Comment: Not only did this work, it ran in about 6 seconds! About 140,000 records out of 250,000 were hit. I ran a validation query, and all went well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to start with, optimize later

```
UPDATE audit_logs O
SET ticket_id = NULL
WHERE (
    SELECT count(distinct ip_address)
    FROM audit_logs I WHERE I.ticket_id = O.ticket_id
) > 1 AND id <> (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id
    FROM audit_logs I WHERE I.ticket_id = O.ticket_id
) AND ip_address <> (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (ip_address) ip_address
    FROM audit_logs I WHERE I.ticket_id = O.ticket_id
)
```

P.S. My PostgreSQL is rusty, so the syntax may be a bit off ... Haven't got PostgreSQL installed on my home machine to check either, sorry.